# xml2 gives an SSL error when connecting to a governmental webpage

Tags: r, httr, xml2

I'm receiving an error on SSL Certificates when I try to use the function `xml2::read_html()` on a Brazilian Government's webpage. 
When I try to access

```
page = xml2::read_html("https://www.gov.br/planalto/pt-br/acompanhe-o-planalto/discursos")
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : 
SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I found another SO question with 3 possible solutions:

```
httr::set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L)) #1
httr::set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = FALSE)) #2
Sys.setenv(LIBCURL_BUILD="winssl") #3
```

None of them solved my problem, then I tried running the code on a Kaggle Notebook, and I received the same error message so I could see the problem isn't on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html:

> Certificate Verification
>
> ...
>
> 1. Tell libcurl to not verify the peer. With libcurl you disable this with curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
>
> With the curl command line tool, you disable this with -k/--insecure.

So, from the command line (or terminal) the following does work:

`curl -k https://www.gov.br/planalto/pt-br/acompanhe-o-planalto/discursos`

the following, as a workaround, also works (using `curl` library):

```
url <- "https://www.gov.br/planalto/pt-br/acompanhe-o-planalto/discursos"
curl::handle_setopt(h, ssl_verifyhost = 0, ssl_verifypeer=0)
curl::curl_download(url=url, destfile = "file_test.html", handle = h)
```

I couldn't find a way to set the *insecure* option within the xml2 package options, which would be the right answer to this question.

Funnily, though, the following also "works", but only to download the html file, to parse it directly, no luck.

```
curl::handle_setopt(h, ssl_verifyhost = 0, ssl_verifypeer=0)
xml2::download_html(url, handle = h)
xml2::read_xml(url, handle = h) #doesnt work
xml2::read_html(url, handle = h) #doesnt work
```

### edit:

actually, following the info [here](https://httr.r-lib.org/reference/httr_options.html), option 181

```
#> 181             ssl_verifypeer             CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  integer
```

should be what you've tried and didn't work. Might be a bug, since it is the same option that works from the command line.